# Copiar por Tag Javascript e HTML

Tags: html, script

Eu tenho quatro arquivos HTML e dentro deles tem várias tabelas 
`<table>`.

Eu estou tentando colocar no final de cada um desses arquivos um código para copiar apenas as tabelas, para que depois eu possa colar no excel e ir organizando. Não estou conseguindo fazer o copiar por tag.

Eu quero fazer um quinto arquivo, que copie todas as tabelas para colar no excel.

```js
<button onclick="copy()">Copiar</button><br>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function copy(){
        var text = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
        var range = document.createRange();

        range.selectNode(table);
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        document.execCommand('copy');

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dante, você está definindo a variável como "*text*" e chamando ela no *selectNode* como "*table*". Além disso, o método *getElementsByTagName* vai retornar um HTMLCollection, então será preciso iterar sobre esta coleção para selecionar cada tabela no *selectNode*.

Infelizmente não é possível copiar o conteúdo de todas as tabelas de uma vez. Vai ser preciso copiar item a item. Uma alternativa para isto é adicionar os itens em uma variável e no final, copiar a variável para o clipboard.

Segue o exemplo do código:

```js
 
function copy() {

    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    var range = document.createRange(); 
    var content = "";

    for (let table of tables) {  

        range.selectNode(table);

        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();        
        window.getSelection().addRange(range); 
        
        document.execCommand('copy');
        content += window.getSelection().toString();
    }  
    
    copyToClipboard(content);
}


function copyToClipboard(text) {
  
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea"); 
    textArea.value = text;  
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);   

    textArea.select();

    document.execCommand('copy');  
    document.body.removeChild(textArea); 
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Devgirl